# How many AOA sensors does the 737 MAX have?

Tags: boeing-737, angle-of-attack, sensors

How many AOA sensors does the 737 MAX have?

Given that it's reported in the media, that one faulty AOA probe activated the MCAS on the Lion Air flight, I was wondering if anybody also knows how an input consensus is reached for the AOA value that gets send to the MCAS system.

Comment: you have two different questions there. would you like to know how many sensors are there, or how consensus is reached?

Comment: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/57626/which-737-generations-doesnt-have-alpha-vane-angle-of-attack-sensor/57634#comment150605_57626 looks relevant.

Comment: @aCVn meh, unsourced

Comment: @Federico Indeed, but still a starting point. And there's the recent news that Boeing is changing some piece of flight software in response to the recent crash. (Sorry, I haven't dug into that further.)

Comment: @aCVn https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49433516#49433516

Comment: @aCVn the answer you posted also only says that the 737 does have an aoa probe and what it´s used for but not how many or how they interact

Comment: @hph304j that's not an answer, it is a comment, and thus you should treat it with skepticism

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Boeing 737 MAX has 2 AoA sensors.

However, MCAS only takes input from 1 AoA sensor at a time.

---

Sources:

The [black box flight recorder data for Lion Air JT610](https://www.seattletimes.com/business/boeing-aerospace/black-box-data-reveals-lion-air-pilots-struggle-against-boeings-737-max-flight-control-system/) shows the data from 2 AoA sensors, labeled "Left" and "Right".

Also, if you [look at the nose of the 737 MAX](https://qz.com/1461400/pilots-werent-informed-of-risks-of-boeing-737-maxs-new-feature/), you will see a left and right AoA vane. (The sensors with the red tags are pitot tubes).

"[Boeing] said it will [change the MCAS software to give the system input from more than one AOA sensor](https://www.seattletimes.com/business/boeing-aerospace/investigators-find-new-clues-to-potential-cause-of-737-max-crashes-as-faa-details-boeings-fix/)."

Comment: Thanks @mike, do you happen to know the manufacturer of the AoA vane on 737 max?

Comment: I really enjoy this answer. Concise and documented.